# Почему PHPSTORM не видит кеш после рестарта?

Tags: phpstorm

После открытия phpstorm приходится делать "Invalidate Caches/Restart", иначе он попросту не видит не то что классы, даже стандартные функции PHP:
[image: скриншот]

PhpStorm: 17.2.4, PHP: 7.1, Laravel 5.4, Symfony3. Как лечить?

Comment: если такое происходит при каждом переоткрытии, скорее всего, индексы портятся в результате какой-то ошибки. Я бы советовала создать support ticket и приаттачить к нему содержимое logs директории (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)

Comment: Установлен ли плагин .gitignore?

Comment: @artspb , установлен.

Comment: Отключение этого плагина должно помочь.